# How do I set the current date in db using Exposed and Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I want to define a column of type date. This column should hold the current date of the resource created. How do i set this up? I'm new to kotlin.

In python, one would impletement it this way: `date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.current_timestamp())`

What's the kotlin equivalent?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you want to just have a datetime column with a default value which will be evaluated on insert of a new record please use `defaultExpression` function:

```
object YourTable : IntIdTable() {
   val dateCreated = datetime("date_created").defaultExpression(CurrentDateTime)
}
```

If you want to generate datetime value on the client side:

```
object YourTable : IntIdTable() {
   val dateCreated = datetime("date_created").clientDefault{ DateTime.now() }
}
```

Comment: It's a class in Exposed which equals to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` SQL expression

Comment: `datetime` requires `exposed-java-time` e.g: `implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-java-time:0.30.1")`

Comment: Very well explained, worked here.